# How do I specify language and architecture when installing a NuGet package?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget, package, nuget-package

When I use `Install-Package` for `Microsoft.Data.Service.Client` version 5.6.4 I get the following downloaded and added:

```
Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.5.6.4.nupkg
lib/net40/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll
lib/net40/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.xml
lib/net40/de/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.resources.dll
lib/net40/es/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.resources.dll
[THE SAME FOR MANY, MANY MORE LANGUAGES]
lib/portable-net45+wp8+win8+wpa/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll
lib/portable-net45+wp8+win8+wpa/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.xml
lib/portable-net45+wp8+win8+wpa/de/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.resources.dll
lib/portable-net45+wp8+win8+wpa/es/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.resources.dll
[THE SAME FOR MANY, MANY MORE LANGUAGES]
lib/sl4/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll
lib/sl4/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.xml
lib/sl4/de/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.resources.dll
lib/sl4/es/Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.resources.dll
[THE SAME FOR MANY, MANY MORE LANGUAGES]
```

As you can see I get a ton of resource modules when I only need English resources and a ton of architectures when I only need one (.NET4 I guess). When this happens for a number of packages I get about two hundred megabytes uneeded binaries.

Is it possible to tell NuGet to just get the language resources I need and only the architectures I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to tell NuGet to just get the language resources I need and only the architectures I need?

The answer is negative. NuGet is the package manager for the Microsoft development platform including .NET. **Nuget can only manage packages as a whole and could not separate package internal files when install the package.** In other words, we could not separate the package into separate packages according to language and framework when we install package.

To resolve this question, we can manually delete language resources and the architectures resources in the package folder that we do not need.

Comment: Will the deleted files be downloaded and restored when I open the project in Visual Studio the next time?

Comment: @sharptooth, No, NuGet restore package based on the package ID, Version and targetFramework  in the package.config/project.json rather than check the entire contents of the package. So those files that are not required by current project will not be restored.